# Call RESTful API while application in background state for indefinite time

Tags: ios, uiapplicationdelegate, nstimeinterval, uibackgroundtask

I want to call a post method every 60 seconds later while application is in background mode.My objective is to store user location and send it to my server.So far, for test purpose I have used `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` and `NSTime` for every 3 seconds call of a temporary post call and it's working fine. But problem is, this background task is being stopped after 10 times call. but I want it to call it indefinite times in certain interval(suppose every 60s or once in a day).

Application iOS Deployment target : 9.0 and its Objective C project with swift compatibility. So far I have done this:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    self.backgroundUpdateTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [self endBackgroundUpdateTask];
    }];
}
- (void) endBackgroundUpdateTask
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask: self.backgroundUpdateTask];
    self.backgroundUpdateTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self endBackgroundUpdateTask];
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 repeats:YES block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {
        [self targetMethod];
    }];
}
```

can anyone help me out how can I call this `targetMethod` in regular interval?

Thanks

Comment: You can't schedule background work like that and you will find plenty of similar questions here. What you can do is get background location updates and if it has been 60s or more since the last time you updated your server, send the update

Comment: Apple has strict rules for background tasks. You can implement bachground fetch.

Comment: @Paulw11 could you please provide a link where I can I get proper solution?

Comment: @Emon Check this tutorial  https://www.raywenderlich.com/5817-background-modes-tutorial-getting-started